# How to calculate sum of items in a List<List<string>> using C#

Tags: c#

I have a `List<List<string>>` .Each item in these List, will be used to display as columns of a report. 
I need to calculate the sum (after converting the string to decimal),of each each column in the report and show it as the footer.
It is not sure, that the number of items in each list will match with other lists.

That means, each item of the lists should be converted and sum up and add in to another list, which will be used to display as the footer row.

Please suggest me, which method would be better to use to achieve this in performance wise.

```
 List<List<string>> test = new List<List<string>>();
 List<string> columnTotal = new List<string>();
 decimal total = 0;
 foreach (var item in test) 
{ 
//Get first element 
// decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal(first element); 
// total =total +dec ; .... 
//Once first element in all the list has been added, 
//columnTotal .add(convert.tostring(total)); 
//Now get the second element ...so on 
}
```

this is my actual requirement.

Comment: Before thinking about performance, write a working code.

Comment: Are you using a "report" library or something like SSRS?  Totals are usually pretty easy in reporting tools.

Comment: "which method would be better", you never showed us any method you have attempted how can we tell you which is better?

Comment: Can you clarify, I still am not sure what you want?

Comment: Why aren't you using strongly typed values, like double, decimal, float, int, etc. instead of strings?

Comment: I have tried to loop through each List<string> in the List<List<string>> and loop thorough each item. And added it to a variable, if it is able to type cast to decimal. In the last of each iteration, adding the total to another list. But for huge records, it was very time consuming.

Comment: Please post your code so we can help you.

Comment: List<List<string>> test = new List<List<string>>();
List<string> columnTotal = new List<string>();
decimal total = 0;
foreach (var item in test)
        {
 //Get first element
 // decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal(first element);
 // total =total +dec ;
 
 ....
 //Once first element in all the list has been added,
 //columnTotal .add(convert.tostring(total));
 //Now get the second element ...so on
        }this is my actual requirement.

Comment: why dont you write it in your question but as comment? edit your question and put this in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try.  I assume you're using a 2D table and not a jagged table.

```
// Assuming a 2D table and not jagged
List<List<string>> table = new List<List<string>>
{
    new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" },              
    new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" },
    new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" },
    new List<string> { "2", "3", "4" }
};

List<decimal> footerTotals = new List<decimal>();

for (int i = 0; i < table[0].Count; i++)
{
    // Sum the columns
    footerTotals.Add(table.Sum(t => decimal.Parse(t[i])));
}

table.ForEach(row => Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\t", row)));
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\t", footerTotals));
```

Results:

```
1       2       3
1       2       3
1       2       3
2       3       4
5       9       13
```

Comment: @sumithps You're welcome.  Kindly click the check mark next to my answer so your question is solved.